# How can I speed up Mouse Keys?

Tags: keyboard, accessibility, mouse-keys

I have been exploring the OS X accessibility option to control the mouse from your keyboard (as described [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1343)) and I am curious if there is a way to make it go faster.

Answer (score 2):

[KeyRemap4Mac](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/index.html) is a nice program that has a large number of various configurations which allow you to modify the function of your keyboard, including the ability to speed up you mouse navigation via the keyboard!

Look in look in `Mouse Keys` section.

Comment: If someone is able to find how to change this from say a bash script, I will be very appreciative, this is just what I'm working off for now...

Answer (score 2):

Step 1:
First I turn off Mouse Keys, then I open Terminal and execute this command:

```
defaults write com.apple.universalaccess mouseDriverInitialDelay -float 0.05
defaults write com.apple.universalaccess mouseDriverMaxSpeed -int 32
```

After re-enabling, mouse starts moving almost immediately.

Step 2:
Install the demo version of ControllerMate ( http://controllermate.com ), and create something similar:

[image: enter code here]

Now pressing the Ctrl key will act as a turbo key, moving your mouse very fast instantly. (If anybody knows an alternative to the otherwise great ControllerMate, please leave a comment.)

Comment: What about the "mouseDriverMaxSpeed" setting as well? Seems like this was set at 32 when I had the speed on max through the UI, increasing to 1000 seems a bit better

Comment: @chrismarx: Hi, I don't see any change on High Sierra. I would be more happy if there were a possibility to change the acceleration. :)